# Laravel Eloquent with() location search

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, geolocation

I'm trying to return a list of Users of type teacher who have an associated teacher profile, their associated class and location who are within 15 miles of a postcode.

It seems to return every user of every type where obj values are null if there is no record for that model and user,its adds the distance to the location correctly but isn't filtering by distance, don't know why.

But what I want is only users with a teacher profile (teacher model) and a location within 15 miles.

The function in my model

```
 public function searchLocationsByDistance($query, $lat, $lng, $max_distance = 15){
    $query->getQuery()->locations = [];
    return $query->select('*')
                 ->selectRaw("( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) )  * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance")
                 ->having('distance', '<=', $max_distance)
                 ->orderBy('distance');

}
```

The Function in my controller

```
  public function search(Request $request){

$input = $request->all();
//Just google api search this populates fine.
$location =  $this->geolocatePostcode( $input['postal_code'] ); 

$instructors=\App\User::with(['teacher', 'teacher.class','teacher.location' => function ($query) 
use($location) {
    $locations = new Location;
    $locations->searchLocationsByDistance($query,$location->lat,$location->lng);
    }])
    //->where('type', '==', 'instructor')
    ->get();

   // var_dump($instructors);
    return response()->json($instructors->toArray());

}
```

Can anyone advise what is wrong with my queries or guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Are your variables correctly replaced within your raw query? There are several ways to do it;

```
->selectRaw("...query some '$lat' more query...")
```

or

```
->selectRaw("...query some {$lat} more query...")
```

You could replace variables in another way as well;

```
->selectRaw("...query some :lat more query...", ['lat' => $lat])
```

Comment: Its returning the distance alias correctly, so one would imagine that bit is at least working.

Justing nothing is filtered, all users even if they don't have a teacher record

Answer (score 0):

The **User** query you've written is going to return everything because there is no filter on that query.  I think using the Laravel method `whereHas()` will help you.

Give this a try, but you'll need to tweak as necessary as I'm guessing at a lot, but this should give you an idea to help:

```
$instructors=\App\User::whereHas(['teacher', function($query) use($location){
     $query->with(['class', 'location' => function($q) use($location){
         $locations = new Location;
         $locations->searchLocationsByDistance($q,$location->lat,$location->lng);
     }])->where('type', '==', 'instructor');
}])
    ->get();
```

Also - newing up the **Location** inside the query may not work as expected and seems complex.  You may wish to pull the filtered list of teachers first, using just `$query->with(['class', 'location']);` on that inner query, and then use the search locations method on that *collection*.  Test both ways to see what is most efficient / works best.